# Splitting field and intersection of subfields

Tags: field-theory, extension-field, splitting-field

Let $K/F$ be a field extension and $f \in F[x]$ with $\deg{(f)} \geq 1$. Furthermore, for a subset $L$ with $F\subseteq L \subseteq K$, let $p(L)$ denote the property that $f$ can be factored completely into linear factors in $L[x]$. Now consider the set
$$\mathcal{L}:=\bigcap\{F\subseteq L \subseteq K \mid p(L) \ \text{holds}\} $$
**Question:** If property $p(K)$ holds, does it follow that $p(\mathcal{L})$ holds?

**In words:** If $f$ can be factored completely into linear factors in $K[x]$, does it follow that $f$ can be factored completely into linear factors in $\mathcal{L}[x]$?

Comment: Is $\mathcal{L}$ supposed to be the *intersection* of those intermediate fields $L$ such that $p(L)$ holds?

Comment: @leoli1 Oh yes you're right, it should be the interesection of all those $L$. I've edited it now.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that is true. Let $\alpha$ be any root of $f$ in $K$. As $\alpha$ is contained in every $L$ such that $p(L)$ holds we have $\alpha\in\mathcal{L}$. Therefore $\mathcal{L}$ contains all roots of $f$ in $K$ and $f$ splits over $K$, so $f$ will also split over $\mathcal L$ since all the linear factors over $K$ are actually defined over $\mathcal L$.

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit more on why $\alpha$ is contained in every $L$ with $p(L)$? I know that $\alpha$ is a root of $f$ in $K$ iff $(x-\alpha)$ is a factor of $f$. Is this factor then also one of the factors in the factorisation of $f$ in $L[x]$ for some $L$ with $p(L)$, and thus a root of $f$ in $L$?

Comment: Yes, that is the reason. Since $f$ splits over $L$ into linear factors we can write $f=\prod_{i}(x-\beta_i)$ for some $\beta_i\in L$. As $f(\alpha)=0$ and we are in fields $\alpha$ has to be one of the $\beta_i$ and hence in $L$

Comment: Okay thanks, it makes sense now.